# Jump to next or previous KEYframe in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'd like to be able to navigate forward and backward through my keyframes using the keyboard.

The code to do this for individual (non-key) frames is simple enough. The following is straight from Flash's "Simple Presentation" template:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_changeSlide);
function fl_changeSlide(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(evt.keyCode == 37) // LEFT
    {
        gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame-1);
    }
    else if (evt.keyCode == 39) // RIGHT
    { 
        gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame+1);
    }
}
stop();
```

Is there an equivalent code snippet for jumping between keyframes? It seems like there should be, but I've not been able to find it.

Comment: Thanks @unkiwii (and Kodiak too) - that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reference to keyframes from the code directly, but you can use labels to name your keyframes and then use that labels to access them from the code.

See [FrameLabel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/FrameLabel.html) and [MovieClip.currentLabels](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentLabels) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately keyframes have no reality in code. You may give them names, or store their indices in an array...

Answer (score 0):

Label to frame names as a, b, c, .Create a button on the page give instance name 'navigationButton'. Then give this code to frame.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

// Current frame index
var currentFrameIndex:int = 0;

// Frame labels array
var frameLabels:Array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

// Add a keyboard event listener to the stage
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
currentFrameIndex = Math.min(currentFrameIndex + 1, frameLabels.length - 1);
} else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
   currentFrameIndex = Math.max(currentFrameIndex - 1, 0);
 }
gotoAndPlay(frameLabels[currentFrameIndex]);
}
```